# Undefined reference to QDeclarativePropertyMap in qt

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am new to Qt.

Qml is facing issue while passing QDeclarativePropertyMap from c++ to Qml.

Here is my code:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QtDeclarative/qdeclarativepropertymap.h>
#include <QVariant>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    ///giving error in below line
    QDeclarativePropertyMap *m_propertymap = new QDeclarativePropertyMap();
    m_propertymap->insert("time" ,QVariant(QString("yet to do")));
    m_propertymap->insert("area" ,QVariant(QString("india")));
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("M_propertymap", m_propertymap);
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

**Error:**

**`undefined reference to QDeclarativePropertyMap QObject`**

Comment: What line is giving the error?

Comment: @MeanGreen QDeclarativePropertyMap *m_propertymap = new QDeclarativePropertyMap();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `QtQml/QQmlPropertyMap` instead

> undefined reference to QDeclarativePropertyMap QObject

is a linker error, cause you trying to mix different versions of qtquick